# Crash error en kotlin : Could not find method oneButton(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Soy nuevo en kotlin

Mi app crashea cuando clickeo cualquier boton,he mirado y cambiado de sitio un viewLabel y en vez de crasearme nada mas iniciar ahora me crashea despues de ese cambio cuando clickeo cualquier botón. Aquí dejo el logcat error:

```
    Process: com.prube.calculator, PID: 4311
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method oneButton(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button_1'
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:436)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:393)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25919)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
2020-04-29 21:59:47.949 4311-4311/com.prube.calculator I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4311 SIG: 9
```

Gracias de antemano a cualquier persona que responda.Si quieren les puedo pasar el código.

Comment: Agrega la definicion del boton en el layout

Comment: Perdona como se hace eso soy nuevo en kotlin Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method
>   oneButton(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick
>   attribute defined on view class
>   androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button_1'

indica que desde el layout donde esta definido el botón con id `button_1` estas haciendo uso del atributo  `android:onClick` que esta llamando al método `oneButton()` pero este no existe.

```
   <Button
    ...
    ...
    android:onClick="oneButton"
    ...
    ...
```

- Si no deseas llamar ese método al dar click en el botón simplemente elimina el atributo y su valor.
- Si deseas llamar ese método, asegura que exista en tu clase.

Comment: solucionado simplemente era que al crear las funiones como parametro de entrada no habia especificado que era una vista